# How can I delete specific lines using awk/sed based on the contents of another file

Tags: bash, shell, debian

How can I delete a specific lines from a file based on line numbers that are contained in another file? I know how to delete specific lines by just providing them on the command line, but I do not know how to delete specific lines based on lines numbers that are contained in another file. The file containing the line numbers is in the following format:

```
15768
15775
15777
15782
15784
15789
15791
15798
15800
15807
15809
15815
15817
15824
15826
```

There are 2073 lines total that I need to remove. I've tried searching around for how to do this although I was not able to an example similar to this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the line numbers to be deleted are in a file `to-be-deleted` and the data is in `big-data-file`, then, using Bash [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
 sed -f <(sed 's/$/d/' to-be-deleted) big-data-file > smaller-data-file
```

The inner `sed 's/$/d'` command converts the line numbers into `sed` delete operations.  The outer `sed` commands reads the delete commands and applies the operations to the big data file.

Comment: I guess that you misread the question.  The title is misleading.  The data file contains a list of _line numbers_ to be deleted.

Comment: @devnull: didn't read the question would probably be nearer accurate.  I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: Yay, `sed` driving `sed`! It's funny `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: it's more fun to write programs that write programs than to write programs… :D

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !(FNR in a)' f1 f2
```

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is the standard editor.

Here's a possibility to drive `ed` to do your edit (in place):

```
#!/bin/bash

ed -s file < <(
    while read line; do
        [[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
        printf "%d d\n" "$line"
    done < lines
    echo "wq"
)
```

this will open the file `file` with `ed`, read the file `lines` that contains the line numbers, check that each read line is indeed a number, then give to `ed` the command to delete that number, and when all is done ask `ed` to write and quit `wq`.

You might want to replace the `[[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue` line by:

```
[[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || { printf >&2 "*** WARNING: Line %d not deleted\n" "$line"; continue; }
```

so as to be warned when invalid lines are present in the file `lines`.

---

Make sure you read glenn jackmann's comment:

> I've heard some older implementations of `ed` do not accept `wq` as a single command: `printf "%s\n" w q`

YMMV.

Comment: I've heard some older implementations of `ed` do not accept `wq` as a single command: `printf "%s\n" w q`