# remove lines based on file input pattern using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have been trying to solve a simple sed line deletion problem. 
Looked [here and there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112590/how-can-i-delete-specific-lines-using-awk-sed-based-on-the-contents-of-another-f). It didn't solve my problem. 
My problem could simply be achieved by using `sed -i'{/^1\|^2\|^3/d;}' infile.txt` which deletes lines beginning with 1,2 and 3 from the infile.txt.

But what I want instead is to take the starting matching patterns from a file than manually feeding into the stream editor.

E.g: deletePattern

```
1 
3
2
```

infile.txt

```
1 Line here
2 Line here
3 Line here 
4 Line here
```

Desired output

```
4 Line here
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You could read `deletepat.txt` into a string, and then try that string as the content of a character class in `sed`. Something like `while read -r ch; do a+=$ch; done <deletepat.txt`. Then `sed -i "{/^[$a]/d;}" infile.txt` (note: you will need to test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `grep` should work:

```
grep -Fvf deletePattern infile.txt
4 Line here
```

But this will skip a line if patterns in `deletePattern` are found anywhere in the 2nd file.

**More accurate results** can be achieved by using this `awk` command:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] && FNR==NR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' deletePattern infile.txt
4 Line here
```

Comment: the grep is an excellent one. awk works but a glitch if the pattern file is empty, it produces empty file. Just try `touch deletePattern` and use awk. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your point regarding `awk` command. I've corrected that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together a quick **command substitution** combined with a **character class** will allow a relatively short oneliner:

```
$ sed -e "/^[$( while read -r ch; do a+=$ch; done <pattern.txt; echo "$a" )]/d" infile.txt
4 Line here
```

Of course, change the `-e` to `-i` for actual in-place substitution.

Comment: It works perfect except when the pattern is an empty file. `touch pattern.txt` and running sed produces _ unterminated address regex_ **error** . Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. And... you got me... I never thought to test it on a blank file. All the different answers just go to show there is always ***more than one way to skin a cat*** in shell computing. Pick your favorite cat!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed` (for `-f -`):

```
sed 's!^[0-9][0-9]*$!/^&[^0-9]/d!' deletePattern | sed -f - infile.txt
```

The first `sed` transforms `deletePattern` into a `sed` script, then the second `sed` applies this script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed '/^[123]/ d' infile.txt
```